# Php Excel Number Formatting

Tags: phpexcel, number-formatting

I have this code to format the cell in number format,

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($colmun_alpha[$total_head+1].$row_total)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
```

The problem is, it is working with other cells but with other cells, it does not work. 
It gives me an output of ###### inside the cell. as you can see in the screenshot.

[Screenshot here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/45361919.png/).

I was wondering what seems to be the problem since I used the same code to format other cells as you can see. If you hover in the #### you can see the value but not displaying like others.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: This column is smaller than others. `870,000.00` is quite a long number, maybe that just doesn't fit?

Comment: Hey, it worked :) I just need to adjust the column width. Thank you so much :)

Comment: This is standard MS Excel behaviour if a value is too large to display in the width of the column.... resize the column in MS Excel, and the value will magically appear once you've increased it enough... try setting the column width to `autofit` in PHPExcel, and it will set the column size to fit the values contained in that column

Comment: Thanks for your information guys. That helped me a lot. I'm just new to programming :) I'll keep that in mind. Thanks again :)